# What is the preferred way to get the full server path in a ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to get the full url to a action when working in a view. I need this to submit to a third party API as a callback. For example what I need is

> http://myserver.com/controller/action

When I use

```
<%= Url.Action("action", "controller") %>
```

I get

> /controller/action

I know several ways to add the server base-path to this but I'm wondering what is the preferred way to do this in the ASP.NET MVC view?

EDIT: Just to clarify, it's not the URL for the current view/action it's for another action in the same controller.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to catch variations in the protocol (http / https), diffrent ports and virtual paths (can't always assume we will be in server root) I ended up with the following solution:

```
<%= Request.Url.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Action("action", "controller")%>
```

I'm working on moving this to a extension method to make it prettier.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: for any view/controller combo, not sure you'll find anything simpler than this.

```
http://<%=Request.Url.Host %><%=Url.Action("action", "controller")%>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post dealing with full path generation called [How to build absolute action URLs using the UrlHelper class](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/Archive/2011/06/30/how-to-build-absolute-action-urls-using-the-urlhelper-class). You would definitely want to check that out!

---

Here's the extension I suggest to write:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method by using
/// the specified action name, controller name and route values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The URL helper.</param>
/// <param name="actionName">The name of the action method.</param>
/// <param name="controllerName">The name of the controller.</param>
/// <param name="routeValues">The route values.</param>
/// <returns>The absolute URL.</returns>
public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url,
    string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null)
{
    string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;

    return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
}
```

Comment: The link to your content here is dead.  Instead of linking to blog posts please post the actual answer.

Comment: @JohnBoker Sorry, I recently broke the redirect rules. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Url returns the full URL including the protocol (http://), the url (www.mydomain.com/mypath), and the querystring (?id=5).

```
@Request.Url       @*Razor tags*@
```

For classic ASP.NET MVC tags it would be

```
<%=Request.Url%>   <%'Classic tags%>
```